# Blank page after geting random number which used in select query

Tags: php, select, random, row

My problem is this: I found a easy and fast way to get random row in my table. First, i am using query, which counts my ids from my table. Second, i generate random number from **1** to result of **count query**. Third, i am selecting row from my table where **id** is equal to my **random generated number**. Everything works fine, but the problem is that sometimes query displays me **blank page** with no information given, with no error given.

**here is my code:**

```
$viso = $stmt = $db->query("select count(id) from intropage")->fetchColumn();
$min=1;
$max= $viso;
$lopas=rand($min,$max);

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM intropage WHERE id='.$lopas.'');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
... }
```

How can i fix this ***"blank page"*** issue?
Thanks to all of you for any answers!

Comment: Just to clarify, it works sometimes? What is the output when it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fast method, because you are using double request to db AND you are exposed to SQL injection. Try:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM intropage ORDER BY RAND() LIMI 1');
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($results as $row) {
    /* */
}
```

I think it will fix your `blank page` error too. If not, turn on error reporting and tell us what error you get.

Comment: well, i knew this method, and i was using this, but i wanted to test that method which i posted. Well, damn.. both of theese answers are good, but i think, that rand() is not fast when table have 500k+ rows.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) activated ?
Your query is wrong so an error is throw and you probably cannot see it

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM intropage WHERE id='".$lopas."'");
```

Also, a better way to have random row, is to use [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM intropage ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```